# faster way to handle T-SQL Result , alternative to CURSOR

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

i am working on a  Report  to generate

- All Fleet movement  a temp table
- All Fleet Stops in a temp table set
- All Fleet idle in a temp table set

i have data like this

```
CREATE TABLE stops
    ([TripStopId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,[ObjectId] int, [DateFrom] varchar(23), [DateTo] varchar(23), [X] int, [Y] int, [ByIgnition] int, [BySpeed0] int, [BySpeed5] int, [BySpeed10] int, [BySpeed15] int, [ByCanSpeed0] int, [ByCanSpeed5] int, [ByCanSpeed10] int, [ByCanSpeed15] int, [GpsDistance] int, [CanDistance] int, [OdometerDistance] int, [Location] int)
;

INSERT INTO stops
    ([ObjectId], [DateFrom], [DateTo], [X], [Y], [ByIgnition], [BySpeed0], [BySpeed5], [BySpeed10], [BySpeed15], [ByCanSpeed0], [ByCanSpeed5], [ByCanSpeed10], [ByCanSpeed15], [GpsDistance], [CanDistance], [OdometerDistance], [Location])
VALUES
    (2729, '2016-01-27 06:21:51.320', '2016-01-27 06:22:27.070', 46.651984, 24.6881872, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0086855611934854, 0, 0, NULL),
    (2729, '2016-01-27 06:22:27.070', '2016-01-27 06:22:54.000', 46.652, 24.6881104, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0667479017095136, 0, 0, NULL),
    (2729, '2016-01-27 06:22:54.000', '2016-01-27 06:23:03.920', 46.651408, 24.68804, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0248830291828213, 0, 0, NULL),
    (2729, '2016-01-27 06:23:03.920', '2016-01-27 06:23:05.920', 46.6511616, 24.6880448, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00384351436414536, 0, 0, NULL),
    (2729, '2016-01-27 06:23:05.920', '2016-01-27 06:23:15.910', 46.651136, 24.6880704, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.104523323509783, 0, 0, NULL),
    (2729, '2016-01-27 06:23:15.910', '2016-01-27 06:25:32.820', 46.6509376, 24.6889936, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.57522938946324, 0, 0, NULL),
    (2729, '2016-01-27 06:25:32.820', '2016-01-27 06:25:53.810', 46.636304, 24.6873888, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0144023488655963, 0, 0, NULL),
    (2729, '2016-01-27 06:25:53.810', '2016-01-27 06:27:14.700', 46.6361632, 24.6874096, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00893761079401728, 0, 0, NULL),
    (2729, '2016-01-27 06:27:14.700', '2016-01-27 06:27:21.680', 46.6360864, 24.6873696, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0369525263958736, 0, 0, NULL),
    (2729, '2016-01-27 06:27:21.680', '2016-01-27 06:27:34.680', 46.6358208, 24.6871408, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0333843719279574, 0, 0, NULL),
    (2729, '2016-01-27 06:27:34.680', '2016-01-27 06:27:45.660', 46.6354912, 24.6871648, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.114545761834751, 0, 0, NULL),
    (2729, '2016-01-27 06:27:45.660', '2016-01-27 06:35:00.480', 46.6346432, 24.6878496, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7.52942986526197, 0, 0, NULL)
;
```

--

```
+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------+------------+------------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+---------------------+-------------+------------------+----------+
| ObjectId |        DateFrom         |         DateTo          |     X      |     Y      | ByIgnition | BySpeed0 | BySpeed5 | BySpeed10 | BySpeed15 | ByCanSpeed0 | ByCanSpeed5 | ByCanSpeed10 | ByCanSpeed15 |     GpsDistance     | CanDistance | OdometerDistance | Location |
+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------+------------+------------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+---------------------+-------------+------------------+----------+
|     2729 | 2016-01-27 06:21:51.320 | 2016-01-27 06:22:27.070 | 46.651984  | 24.6881872 |          1 |        0 |        0 |         0 |         0 |           0 |           0 |            0 |            0 | 0.0086855611934854  |           0 |                0 |          |
|     2729 | 2016-01-27 06:22:27.070 | 2016-01-27 06:22:54.000 | 46.652     | 24.6881104 |          1 |        1 |        1 |         0 |         0 |           0 |           0 |            0 |            0 | 0.0667479017095136  |           0 |                0 |          |
|     2729 | 2016-01-27 06:22:54.000 | 2016-01-27 06:23:03.920 | 46.651408  | 24.68804   |          1 |        1 |        1 |         1 |         1 |           0 |           0 |            0 |            0 | 0.0248830291828213  |           0 |                0 |          |
|     2729 | 2016-01-27 06:23:03.920 | 2016-01-27 06:23:05.920 | 46.6511616 | 24.6880448 |          1 |        1 |        1 |         0 |         0 |           0 |           0 |            0 |            0 | 0.00384351436414536 |           0 |                0 |          |
|     2729 | 2016-01-27 06:23:05.920 | 2016-01-27 06:23:15.910 | 46.651136  | 24.6880704 |          1 |        1 |        1 |         1 |         0 |           0 |           0 |            0 |            0 | 0.104523323509783   |           0 |                0 |          |
|     2729 | 2016-01-27 06:23:15.910 | 2016-01-27 06:25:32.820 | 46.6509376 | 24.6889936 |          1 |        1 |        1 |         1 |         1 |           0 |           0 |            0 |            0 | 1.57522938946324    |           0 |                0 |          |
|     2729 | 2016-01-27 06:25:32.820 | 2016-01-27 06:25:53.810 | 46.636304  | 24.6873888 |          1 |        1 |        1 |         1 |         0 |           0 |           0 |            0 |            0 | 0.0144023488655963  |           0 |                0 |          |
|     2729 | 2016-01-27 06:25:53.810 | 2016-01-27 06:27:14.700 | 46.6361632 | 24.6874096 |          1 |        0 |        0 |         0 |         0 |           0 |           0 |            0 |            0 | 0.00893761079401728 |           0 |                0 |          |
|     2729 | 2016-01-27 06:27:14.700 | 2016-01-27 06:27:21.680 | 46.6360864 | 24.6873696 |          1 |        1 |        1 |         0 |         0 |           0 |           0 |            0 |            0 | 0.0369525263958736  |           0 |                0 |          |
|     2729 | 2016-01-27 06:27:21.680 | 2016-01-27 06:27:34.680 | 46.6358208 | 24.6871408 |          1 |        1 |        1 |         1 |         1 |           0 |           0 |            0 |            0 | 0.0333843719279574  |           0 |                0 |          |
|     2729 | 2016-01-27 06:27:34.680 | 2016-01-27 06:27:45.660 | 46.6354912 | 24.6871648 |          1 |        1 |        1 |         1 |         0 |           0 |           0 |            0 |            0 | 0.114545761834751   |           0 |                0 |          |
|     2729 | 2016-01-27 06:27:45.660 | 2016-01-27 06:35:00.480 | 46.6346432 | 24.6878496 |          1 |        1 |        1 |         1 |         1 |           0 |           0 |            0 |            0 | 7.52942986526197    |           0 |                0 |          |
+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------+------------+------------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+---------------------+-------------+------------------+----------+
```

This data for each car move  and its start X,Y, AND total Distance,

any way better than CURSOR as i believe CURSOR is SLOW,  to make the following

- list all drives ,  and X,Y  from the start drive and x,y of the next drive stop
  grouped by Objectid
- list all Stops ,  and its X,Y  as Stop mean time between each 2 drive rows 
  grouped by Objectid  "for same object in reportgroup"

i am asking about best way as this report can have more than 1 million tripstop row

Thats the expected result  i have by CURSOR , it take long time to output

```
    +----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+---------+--------------+--------------+------------+------------+---------------------+------------+----------+-------------+----------+
| ObjectId |        DateFrom         |         DateTo          |     X      |     Y      |     X2     |     Y2     | IsMoving | Distance | Location | AvgSpeed | DriverId | Driver | IButtonId | DateYear | DateMonth | DateWeek | DateDay | StartGeoName | StartAddress | EndGeoName | EndAddress | DeductionPointValue | PoiAtStart | PoiAtEnd | DrivingTime | StopTime |
+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+---------+--------------+--------------+------------+------------+---------------------+------------+----------+-------------+----------+
|     2729 | 2016-01-27 06:21:51.320 | 2016-01-27 06:22:27.070 | 46.651984  | 24.6881872 | 46.652     | 24.6881104 |        0 | 0.01     |          | 0.87     | NULL     | NULL   | NULL      |     2016 |         1 |        5 |      27 |              | NULL         | NULL       | NULL       | 0.01                | NULL       | NULL     |           0 |    35750 |
|     2729 | 2016-01-27 06:22:27.070 | 2016-01-27 06:25:53.810 | 46.652     | 24.6881104 | 46.6361632 | 24.6874096 |        1 | 1.79     |          | 31.16    | NULL     | NULL   | NULL      |     2016 |         1 |        5 |      27 |              | NULL         | NULL       | NULL       | 1.8                 | NULL       | NULL     |      206740 |        0 |
|     2729 | 2016-01-27 06:25:53.810 | 2016-01-27 06:27:14.700 | 46.6361632 | 24.6874096 | 46.6360864 | 24.6873696 |        0 | 0.01     |          | 0.4      | NULL     | NULL   | NULL      |     2016 |         1 |        5 |      27 |              | NULL         | NULL       | NULL       | 1.81                | NULL       | NULL     |           0 |    80890 |
|     2729 | 2016-01-27 06:27:14.700 | 2016-01-27 06:35:00.480 | 46.6360864 | 24.6873696 | NULL       | NULL       |        1 | 7.71     |          | 59.62    | NULL     | NULL   | NULL      |     2016 |         1 |        5 |      27 |              | NULL         | NULL       | NULL       | 9.52                | NULL       | NULL     |      465780 |        0 |
+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+---------+--------------+--------------+------------+------------+---------------------+------------+----------+-------------+----------+
```

Comment: Some sample output would help

Comment: @TheGameiswar done updated my question with sample output

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: If you include your current working cursor it will be much easier to help optimize it.

Comment: i have done what @SeanLange asked to do  , now question is more clear

Comment: Your sample data won't work as posted because you defined ObjectId as the primary key and every row has the same value. Even without that a little explanation of what you are trying to do would go a LONG way here. Just a table of random data and some output from that which appears random makes it nearly impossible for somebody to help here. We need to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: i have update the sample , ObjectId not a primary , table have IDENTITY column

i am trying to found some thing better than CURSOR here  ,what i have done with CURSOR is loop over result and for each 2 row , add a new row to drive temp table  and  subtract them to get stop row to stop table , and so on , and thats extremely slow

Comment: 1. You'd be better to provide smaller sample data. 2. I think each records in sample data shows the start and stop time and location, Right? 3. Does provided sample belongs to to a single trip? What SQL version are you using?

Comment: @FLICKER i have update the question to make my sample smaller , and yes belong same trip , each row equal sub trip , iam using sql server 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with cte as
(
select tripstopid,datefrom,dateto,x,y,byspeed0,
case when lag(byspeed0,1,'') over(order by datefrom,dateto) = byspeed0 then 0 else 1 end as ischange from stops
),cte1 as
(
select t.*,
 (select sum(ischange)  from cte where tripstopid <= t.tripstopid) groupno
from cte t
),cte3 as
(
select *,row_number() over(partition by groupno order by tripstopid) as rn1 from cte1 
),cte4 as
(
select *from cte3 
where rn1=1
)
select *from cte4 c1 left
join cte4 c2  on c1.groupno+1 =c2.groupno
order by c1.datefrom
```

Comment: Although you need to add some more columns to above query

Comment: thanks its working great , and correct result as expected

Comment: @ArunPeddakotla This query is limited to a number of stops, since you need one CTE for each stop. In the example are four stops, but could be more or less in a real scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this to be sure that I have no errors, but something like this should do the trick.  The idea is to group values together based on the BySpeed0 column then aggregate.

```
WITH AdjacentValues AS (
  /*
  This adds the prior BySpeed0 value to the row
  */
  SELECT
    ObjectID,
    DateFrom,
    DateTo,
    X,
    Y,
    [BySpeed0] AS 'IsMoving',
    LAG([BySpeed0]) OVER (PARTITION BY ObjectID ORDER BY DateFrom ASC) AS 'PriorValue'
  FROM
    stops
), GroupedResults AS (
  /*
  This will create a number that increments every time the current BySpeed0 value is not the same as the next one.
  */
  SELECT
    ObjectID,
    DateFrom,
    DateTo,
    X,
    Y,
    IsMoving,
    NextValue,
    SUM(IIF(IsMoving <> PriorValue, 1, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY ObjectID ORDER BY DateFrom ASC) AS 'GroupingValue'
  FROM
    AdjacentValues
), AggregateResult AS (
  /*
  This will Select the minimum date and maximum date for a particular grouping
  */
  SELECT
    ObjectID,
    MIN(DateFrom) AS 'DateFrom',
    MAX(DateTo) AS 'DateTo'
  FROM
    AdjacentValues
  GROUP BY
    ObjectID,
    GroupingValue
)
  /*
  This will add the X/Y information
  */
  SELECT 
    R.*,
    A.X,
    A.Y,
    AA.X AS 'X2',
    AA.Y AS 'Y2'
  FROM
    AggregateResult R
  LEFT JOIN
    AdjacentValues A
  ON
    A.DateFrom = R.DateFrom
    AND A.ObjectID = R.ObjectID
  LEFT JOIN 
    AdjacentValues AA
  ON
    AA.DateTo = R.DateTo
    AND A.ObjectID = R.ObjectID
```

P.S. If you are using spatial data at all, it would only take minor adjustments to turn these coordinate pairs into geometry/geography lines.

Comment: its nice that you use lag here , but for me after testing
we have missing NextValue column from where i can catch it ?

Comment: i manged to get your answer work its great but you have problem in define next x,y
@Arun Peddakotla answer is more correct ans working fast same as you , thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the core query, where you can include your other calculated columns:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT S.*
FROM stops S
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT A.TripStopId AS TA, B.TripStopId AS TB
    FROM stops A
    INNER JOIN stops B ON A.ObjectId = B.ObjectId AND A.DateTo = B.DateFrom 
    WHERE A.BySpeed0 = 0 AND B.BySpeed0 = 1) T ON S.TripStopId = T.TA OR S.TripStopId = T.TB
)
SELECT CTE.TripStopId, CTE.ObjectId, CTE.DateFrom, CTE.DateTo, CTE.X, CTE.Y, S.X AS X2, S.Y AS Y2, CTE.BySpeed0 AS IsMoving
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN stops S ON CTE.ObjectId = S.ObjectId
    AND ((CTE.BySpeed0 = 0 AND S.BySpeed0 = 1 AND CTE.DateTo = S.DateFrom)
        OR (CTE.BySpeed0 = 1 AND S.BySpeed0 = 0 AND CTE.DateTo <= S.DateFrom))
```